# How can I store a bigint as an nvarchar in a SQL Server table without scientific notation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to store a numeric value in a SQL table as a string (due to some IDs containing non-numeric characters) but I am having trouble achieving this without it being stored with scientific notation, which wouldn't be a problem if I could adjust this in the view, but it loses the last few numbers when doing so.

I have tried (like you would with a query) casting it into a `bigint` and then an `nvarchar` in the `INSERT INTO` statement, but that doesn't affect how it is stored.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customer_comp](
    [customer_ref] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [customer_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [customer_comp] 
    (customer_ref, customer_name)
VALUES
    ('199000243', 'John Smith'),
    ('CR-222-3X0D', 'Jane Smith');
```

Expected results:

```
+--------------+---------------+
| customer_ref | customer_name |
+--------------+---------------+
| 199000243    | John Smith    |
| CR-222-3X0D  | Jane Smith    |
+--------------+---------------+
```

Results I keep getting:

```
+--------------+---------------+
| customer_ref | customer_name |
+--------------+---------------+
| 1.9900e+003  | John Smith    |
| CR-222-3X0D  | Jane Smith    |
+--------------+---------------+
```

In the event that I'm going about this in completely the wrong way, I'm storing it this way as some values are stored in an Alpha Numeric format such as 'AAA-NNNA-NNAA' and some values are all numeric 'NNNNNNNN' so require the column to accept nvarchar.

Comment: What sort of numbers do you have? I've tried with `1254654522316465463` and it just gets cast to `'1254654522316465463'`.

Comment: `SELECT CAST(CAST(customer_ref AS bigint) AS nvarchar(50))`? How's your data looks like? What are you trying to do really, don't you think storing numbers as strings is wrong?

Comment: What's the datatype of `customer_ref`? If you got a BIGINT why do you want to store it in a NVARCHAR(50)?

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I need to store it because the 'customer_ref' can also contain some text characters with prefixes and apostrophes which I need to keep the format of.

Comment: If you want to keep *prefixes and apostrophes* why do you cast it to a BIGINT first?

Comment: @dnoeth that's a good observation. It's a union query and the table I was importing from only contains numeric IDs and these are the ones that are displaying scientific notation.

Comment: Usually the first Select of a Union determines the resulting datatype, try CASTing here.

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? If dnoeth's hint does not help you, please try to set up a [mcve] (with DDL, sample data and expected output

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo - I have updated the question with a more basic example of expected results and method.

Comment: @RazorKillBen please use the same ddl as in your original table. Now the code is a string type and won't show the bad behavior... A [mcve] should reproduce the error...

Comment: Sorry @JeroenMostert - I wrote the example data from memory of the formatting and `'1.9900e+003` isn't the actual value it would create if I did do that. Are you saying it's impossible for me to store a string numeric value without the converted notation?

Comment: You could use the `format()` function and specify your desired format

Comment: Sorry @Shnugo - I have set this up exactly the way I have in my application just minimally, and this is exactly the datatype I am using and exactly the results I am receiving.

Comment: Thank you @lakta - this worked. This lead me to realise that the reason this wasn't working, was because the data was going into the table as `CAST(CAST(customer_ref as bigint) as nvarchar(50))` much like you would get out the data in this format in a query. Thank you @Shnugo for spurring me to come to this conclusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase anyone stumbles across this in future, you can quite simply `INSERT INTO` without casting the data in anyway. Casting the numeric value into a `bigint` and then into a `nvarchar` after like the below will cause the scientific notation to be stored:

```
CAST(CAST(customer_ref as bigint) as nvarchar(50))
```